# temporary unbind mouseenter from element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make hover and click events for an element both animate the same (in this case `top`) property.

look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XC9Xu/1/

There is an `a` fixed at the top with `top:-50px` and `height=100px`,

1- when you hover it's top animates to `top=0` and on mouseleave top becomes `top=-50` again.

2- on click: animate `top=200px`

So the problem is, you click and dont move the cursor, everything is fine, but as soon as you move the cursor it says: hey, where is the element I was over it, I am not over it now, go back to `top=-50px` :D

I need to tell it forget about the past and look to the future!

**What I expect:
I expect that the element remain at `top=300px` after click and don't come back to `top=-50px` when you move the mouse after click. Then if you move your cursor again over it its top goes from 300 to 0 and so on...**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a')
    .hover(
        function(){
            $(this).animate({top:0});
        },
        function(){
            $(this).animate({top:-50});
        }
    )
    .on("click",function(){
        $(this).animate({top:300});
    });

});

 a{
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top:-50px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set a flag, and use it to enable/disable the hover functionality.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XC9Xu/3/)

```
var click_triggered = false;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a')
    .hover(
        function(){
            if(!click_triggered){
                $(this).animate({top:0});
            }
        },
        function(){
            if(!click_triggered){
                $(this).animate({top:-50});
            }
        }
    )
    .on("click",function(){
        click_triggered = true;
        $(this).animate({top:300});       
    });

});
```

or if you wanted it to revert after a second click you would do something like this click handler:

```
    .on("click",function(){
        click_triggered = !click_triggered;
        $(this).animate({top:300});       
    });
```

Comment: nope! I now about the flag trick and I've tried that. I am seeking more elegant solution. for example using .unbind() or something...btw, using your code, where you suggest to set flag to false again?

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     reduceHeight =  function(){
            $(this).animate({top:-50});
     };

    $('a')
    .hover( function(){
            $(this).animate({top:0});
            $(this).bind('mouseleave', reduceHeight);
     })
    .click( function(){
        $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
        $(this).animate({top:300});
    });

});
```